# Facebook Apps - Canvas size

Tags: javascript, facebook, canvas, size

I'm new to Facebook apps. How to set the right size for my canvas? Let's say 520*600...

Tried: `<script type="text/javascript"> FB.Canvas.setSize({ width: 520, height: 600 }); </script>`

Didn't change anything...

Comment: Please tell us what you have already tried and what went wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript"> FB.Canvas.setSize({ width: 520, height: 600 }); </script>
```

Also must be added: `<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>`

Comment: That's why you need to research the documentation more before asking.  It does clearly state you need the all.js script linked up to your script.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    FB.Canvas.setSize({ width: 520, height: 600 }); // Live in the past
</script>
```

Comment: yes it is possible, but don't know all the steps to do it: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.setSize/

Comment: Just like this doesn't work, must be something else included...

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
FB.Canvas.setSize({ width: 520, height: 600 });
</script>

Comment: sure, it's base of javasccript... I thought you know it

Comment: should there be some other sdks included?